# Как создать каталог на рабочем столе для любого пользователя?

Tags: python, ос

Нужна программа создающая каталог "test" на рабочем столе. При этом пользователь не должен вводить путь для создания папки. Также, программа должна работать у любого пользователя (не важно откуда программа открыта - нужно чтобы папка "test" создавалась на любом рабочем столе.

Я так понимаю нужно использовать что-то подобное `%USERNAME%` в CMD.

Программа должна умещаться в один .py файл, чтобы потом её можно было скомпилировать в .exe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для Python 3.x:

```
from pathlib import Path

(Path.home() / "Desktop" / "test").mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
```

---

[ассоциация](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34275782/how-to-get-desktop-location):

```
path = os.path.join(os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~')), 'Desktop')
os.makedirs(os.path.join(path, "test"), exist_ok=True)
```